# Mount NTFS on OS X

Tags: macos, mount, ntfs

I am having trouble mounting one of my NTFS drives in OS X.

I've added the following entry to my fstab with the 'vifs' command.

```
UUID=UUID_FROM_DISK_UTILITY /data ntfs rw,auto,nobrowse
```

I have created the /data mountpoint with 'mkdir /data' and attempted to mount with 'mount -a'.

I get the following error:

```
mount_ntfs: UUID=UUID_FROM_DISK_UTILITY on /data: No such file or directory
```

Edit: I can mount with the disk utility, but not from the terminal.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

http://sourceforge.net/projects/native-ntfs-osx/files/

Native solution. No 3rd party drivers or software installs.

Answer (score 0):

I've only ever mounted NTFS drives in `/Volumes/` so what happens if you replace the `/data` with `none` and allow the System to choose the mount name?